# Gem install better_errors won't work with ruby 2.0.0-rc2

Tags: ruby, rbenv, better-errors-gem

I'm using rbenv with two versions of ruby 2.1.2 and 2.0.0-rc2 (the same we use in production).

```
➜  astreal git:(feature/better-bower) rbenv versions
   system
 * 2.0.0-rc2 (set by /Users/vivien/Documents/bannerman/bannerman/.ruby-version)
   2.1.2
```

When I'm using the version 2.0.0-rc2 the installation of the project gems does not work due to the following:

```
➜  astreal git:(feature/better-bower) gem install better_errors --version 2.0.0
   ERROR:  Error installing better_errors:
      better_errors requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

whereas obviously the version I use is >= 2.0.0

The solution so far as been to fork `better_errors` and require a version > 1.9. Which is obviously not great.

Has anyone any ideas?